# CSS3 Rotate from the left?

Tags: css, animation, rotation, position

I'm trying to make kind of a "fold-in" effect for a submenu, but i'm having some issues.

See this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lotav

As you can see, by default the submenu has a rotation of 90 deg. When a menu item is hovered, the submenu animates to 0 deg, giving it kind of a folding effect. The problem is, when the submenu starts animating (at 90 deg), it's centered within it's width. Even though the submenu has a width of X pixels, when rotated, the width shrinks and it is then centered within the actual width (X). To achieve the wanted effect, the submenu would have to be *positioned to the left when rotated*.

The second issue, which i find really strange, is that although i have set the rotation of the submenu to 90 deg, it doesn't quite appear so. It kind of overlaps a little bit. 90 deg should make it completely vertical (and therefore invisible), or am i missing something?

I've only tested the effect in Chrome 24 and Firefox 18. I can't get the 3d effect to work in Firefox, it kind of just shrinks in width, while in chrome you can actually see it rotate. I have the auto-prefix option turned on in the codepen, but i don't know whether it works correctly or not.

Here's a demo of the disired effect: http://davidwalsh.name/demo/folding-animation.php

The only difference is i want it to "fold in" from the left instead of the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue:change the default `transform-origin` for the submenu. Use:

```
transform-origin: left;
```

Second issue is caused by `perspective: 1000;` - if you remove it and add it just on hover you won't have this problem.

[**demo**](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/AHlnz).

Comment: Transform-origin is exactly what i needed! I do however need the perspective there. Putting it in the hover state is the equivalent of removing it entirely, or it yields the same result at least. In your demo it just looks flat, as if the width is just pushed together. In my demo, with the perspective in the `li`, you can see it kind of "turn" (it gives it a 3d effect). I figured the perspective had something to do with the overlapping of the rotation, but removing it just messed it up more. Do you see the difference?

Comment: I managed to fix it, kind of. Using `backface-visability` i just hid the overlapping part: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwcaI